# Identify unique visitor redirected from Qualtrics

Tags: uniqueidentifier, qualtrics, utm

I'm trying to redirect respondents within a survey in Qualtrics to a webpage. On this webpage, they need to choose between a couple of options, and after it return to Qualtrics.

I know it is possible to generate an unique URL within qualtrics (e.g. example.com/test?UniqueID=999). However, how can I 'catch' this parameter together with the participant's response?

Thank you!

Comment: You probably need to look into some type of API options available by Qualtrics and then set up some sort of endpoint on your webserver to handle this API redirect.

Answer (score 0):

To "catch" a parameter in Qualtrics, you need to create an embedded data block in your survey flow and then create an embedded data field within that block with the same name (case-sensitive!) as the parameter.  Instructions are available in the Qualtrics documentation [here](https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/survey-flow/standard-elements/embedded-data/).

Please note that if you want to ensure that the parameter will be recorded for all responses, you should place the embedded data block first in your survey flow.  (If it's placed after the question block(s), it will only be recorded for respondents who complete all the questions.)